# Android drawLine on cameraIntent

Tags: android, view, intentservice

I am currently writing on a panoramic app in android. A camera intent is started in the onCreate method of my mainactivity when I run the app.

I want to add a line in the middle of the screen, when the intent is started. 
I tried the following codes:

Call the DrawView class from MainActivity. Line is only shown after my video is saved

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
mDrawView = new DrawView(c);
mDrawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
setContentView(mDrawView);
```

I tried to make a second Activity with an static class - Line was shown at the beginning but my VideoIntent did not start

```
public class DrawView extends Activity {
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new LineView(this));
  }

private static class LineView extends View
{
  private Paint paint = new Paint();

  public LineView(Context context) {
     super(context);
     setFocusable(true); }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  }
  }
  }
```

What is the best way to show the line? Can I implement an IntentService? How would I call it from my MainActity?

Comment: If you want to draw on a camera, use the camera APIs to implement your own camera code, then draw on your preview. There are countless camera apps that could be started by your "camera intent", and you have no way to know if your line will interfere with the user's use of any of those apps. You also have no way of knowing if the camera app is in the foreground or if the user left it to go do something else (e.g., answer a phone call).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, but what could I do to show the line the whole time regardless of whether the camera app is in the foreground or not